# What exactly happened with Kenny in Shut Up and Dance

Tags: plot-explanation, black-mirror

In the end of the episode the mother of Kenny calls him and apparently has seen a video of him masturbating to child porn. She must have seen it to believe it.

Considering that the camera is attached to the screen, how can the video contain what was on the screen at that time?

Was there another camera or is it just a plot hole (my initial guess)?

Comment: I've seen this episode a long time ago, but I think there were probably sounds of the porn video rerecorded in the compromising video... and the pirates probably informed the mother saying "here is your son watching child porn". Then when the mother confronts him, he didn't seem to deny.

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66542/did-kenny-from-shut-up-and-dance-in-black-mirror-really-do-what-they-say-he-di

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of it gets buried under the music, but her line on the phone is

> "What did you do Kenny? They say it's kids; that you've been looking
>   at kids. & Lucy saw it, it was a video of you. You're doing
>   *[indistinguishable]* & all her friends have got it. Kids Kenny."

The rest is less distinct, but it doesn't mean she saw what he was looking at, nor even the act itself.
Going by what she said, she's only heard it reported.

That does, of course, simply remove the problem to one remote - if his mother didn't see it, who actually did & what did they actually see... somebody either saw

1. him **and** what he saw, from an undisclosed camera [unlikely]
2. only a report of what happened, or
3. the antagonist posted both, the web-cam video & screen caps etc from his computer

That the police turn up mob-handed mere seconds later makes for good drama, but we have to assume they wouldn't come out in such numbers for mere hearsay. They also don't know at that point that he'd killed the guy in the woods, unless the drone footage was also sent to them along with the other evidence.

*Late thought - they knew where he was, so they probably **have** seen the drone footage too.*

If that's correct & the police did have the drone footage, then whether or not he was actually watching child porn, by that time to the police, is probably almost moot. They're coming to arrest a killer.

The only 'direct evidence' we do see is the CEO 'racist email' scandal on her screen, with a newspaper report & excerpt from one of the emails.

I think we're left to assume similar details were provided for the other 'victims' - so whether it's a true plot hole or not, I'm not really sure.

Comment: The hackers who blackmailed him are clearly sophisticated. It isn't ridiculous to assume they hacked the porn site containing the source video not just Kenny's webcam. So they could easily have distributed the webcam video footage alongside the porn video. In fact the blackmail probably wouldn't work if they didn't have the capacity to do this. So: no plot hole.

Comment: @matt_black - agree. As in many Black Mirror episodes, they're not really too concerned with the how & why, just "that it did happen", so I'm on the side of 'no plot hole' really.